# Merge column data with a IFeatureClass

Tags: arcobjects, c#, arcgis-engine

I have a points shapefile with City, State, Zip columns.  I want to merge the column data together into a new column containing: City-State-Zip (with the hyphen).

Can I merge column data like this using a IFeatureClass?  If not what should I try?

Comment: Is a Calculate Field or IFeatureCursor operation not within the scope of this task?

Comment: Let me type you up an answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on whether you want to update all rows or just the selected row, you could make use of [IFeatureClass's](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/IFeatureClass_Interface/0025000002qs000000/) Search or Update methods to obtain an [IFeatureCursor](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/IFeatureCursor_Interface/0025000002vs000000/) that you could then use to create your concatenated attribute value and then plop it into the `IFeature` using `IFeature.Value` if I'm not mistaken.

Personally, however, I always prefer to cast an IFeatureClass to an ITable. I just find myself more comfortable working with them. :)

Comment: +1 Don't forget to call ReleaseComObject on the cursor when done with it.